# how can i insert the array of id into a single field of data base

Tags: php, sql

hi how can i insert the array of service id into table into a single field like 2,3,4 in database i am confuse please help followingis my code...i am using this but it is inserted only single id..

```
$service=implode(",",$_POST['service']);

$sqlQuery="INSERT INTO ".DBPROMOTION." SET 
            promotion_service_id='".$service."', 
            promotion_user_id='".$user."', 
            promotion_discount='".$_POST['discount'].$_POST['type']."',
            promotion_title='".$_POST['title']."',
            promotion_start_date='".$startDate."', 
            promotion_end_date='".$endDate."', 
            promotion_code='".$_POST['code']."', 
            promotion_description='".$_POST['desc']."'"
```

Comment: you chould realy work on your accept-rate - with 0%, people won't be very motivated to help you. please take a look at your old questions, and if there is an answer that solved you problem, click the tick-mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use two database tables with relation one-to-many to link more than one element with table columnt. That would be better design.

You may insert all id's into db in form of string, but I don't think, that is what you aiming for.

Also, you should sanitize your input from $_POST before entering int to db, to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

you database-model seem to be not [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - correct that first before programming an application that will cause some realy big problems in the future.

also, you should never insert posted data directly to avoid [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or, better, [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.pdo.php) for prepared statements.

to your problem directly: i think 'promotion_service_id' is an integer-field - '2,3,4' is a string, so (fortunately) you have no chance to insert it.